# Laravel 5.6 - Store PassPort keys

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-passport

I am using Passport in a Laravel 5.6 project and all is working great in my local environment.

However, when I deploy it to Amazon I have to run the following to generate the client and secrets.

```
php artisan passport:install
```

This works, but it means the keys change everytime I deploy a new version. Is there a way to keep the same keys?

Can they be stored somewhere?

Comment: How are you deploying .. are you using EBS?